# CSS: Dynamic width of element inside div

Tags: html, css

How can I go about making the `floating-text` div below have a dynamic width, so it will fill the space beside the image? The image can be all from 100px to 400px wide.

```
<div id="container">
  <img src="image-can-be-from-100-to-400px-wide.jpg">
  <div id="floating-text">
    Text to be floated:left on right side of the image.
    The width of this div needs to be dynamic, 
    so it will fill out the open space on the right side of the image above.
  </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#container {
  width: 700px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#floating-text {
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/51zstw6b/

Comment: you want <div id="floating-text"> below the image no matter how much width of the image right?

Comment: it should float on the right side of the image. where the div is in the html doesnt matter.

Comment: If you can, I would include a link to jsfiddle.net or codepen.io to show what your code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give image a float: left and remove the float for the floating-text.

CSS

```
#container {
  width: 500px; /*width adjusted for this fiddle demo*/
  padding: 20px;
}

.img {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#floating-text {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/burw0o9f/)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what your working with. If you want to keep old browsers happy you could add an align property to the image. `align="top"` for instance tells the image to float text to the top of the image. This doesn't float the image, it actually tells the text to wrap around the image.

If you're using modern standards you can replace it with a css-class like this:

```
.float-image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

This should float your text around the image and add a proper margin so the text wouldn't wrap into the image.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this CSS:

```
#floating-text {
  float: left;
   width: 40%;
}
img {
    float:left;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Note: the css on `#container` is removed

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#container {
  width: 700px;
  padding: 20px;
}

#container img
{
    float:left;
}

#floating-text {
  margin-left: 20px;
  float:left;
    width:200px;    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest thing you could think of is using a **CSS Flexbox**

**HTML :**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/aaaaaa/444444.png&text=400x400" />
  <div id="floating-text">
    Text to be floated:left on right side of the image.
    The width of this div needs to be dynamic, 
    so it will fill out the open space on the right side of the image above.
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 700px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
}
img {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#floating-text {
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/94bLqe9d/

Comment: You need to add support for those not using css3. Flex-boxes are not supported by that many browsers yet.